# NullPointerException when testing resource in dropwizard with mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, dropwizard

I built a restful API with dropwizard. And now I want to test it with [what dropwizard document provided](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/testing.html).

```
public class BlogCommentResourceTest {
private static final BlogCommentDAO dao = mock(BlogCommentDAO.class);
private final BlogComment blogComment = new BlogComment(1, "url", "comment", new Date(), "name");
@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
        .addResource(new BlogCommentResource(dao)).build();
List<BlogComment> list = new ArrayList<BlogComment>();

@Before
public void setUp(){
    list.add(blogComment);

    when(dao.getLast()).thenReturn(blogComment);
    when(dao.getAll(POJOs.BlogCommentPOJO.toString())).thenReturn(list);
}
@After
public void tearDown(){
    reset(dao);
}
@Test
public void getLast(){
    assertThat(resources.client().target("/blogcomments").request().get(List.class))
            .isEqualTo(list);
    verify(dao.getAll(POJOs.BlogCommentPOJO.toString()), times(1));
}
```

}

This is the method I want to test.

```
enter code here
```

And error message is shown as below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at dao.DAOBase.getAll(DAOBase.java:37)
at dao.BlogCommentDAO.getAll(BlogCommentDAO.java:19)
at resource.BlogCommentResourceTest.setUp(BlogCommentResourceTest.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule$1.evaluate(ResourceTestRule.java:202)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Somebody know what happened? Why it is the DAOBase that throw a null pointer? My unit test for all of dao shows they works well.

Comment: I'd expect `POJOs.BlogCommentPOJO.toString()` is not being passed into `DAOBase`, otherwise your mock would be returning your list.

Comment: I think the issue is in the `setUp()` method. `at resource.BlogCommentResourceTest.setUp(BlogCommentResourceTest.java:29)` The only thing from a glance that I can see causing it is `POJOs.BlogCommentPOJO.toString()` returning `null`. Can you run the test, drop a breakpoint on that line and check?

Comment: Thank you guys, I fix it. `BlogCommentDAO` is the object I mock, but actually I am trying to invoke method in BlogCommentDAO's superclass. I cancels their inheritance relationship, and copy the method to BlogCommentDAO, and it work.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown in `dao.DAOBase.getAll(DAOBase.java:37)` because the mock of `dao` returns null for `dao.DAOBase`. You seem to be mocking a class here, not an interface and are trying to access a field of this mocked class. This is *not* going to work, Mockito is designed to mock interface with class support being limited, and within that, to mock method behaviour, not field values.

To work around you the easiest is to turn your `BlogCommentDAO` into an interface or at least to have *no* public fields on it if it is a class, which then can be easily mocked like

```
DAOBase daoBaseMock = mock(DAOBase.class)
doReturn(allThings).when(daoBaseMock).getAll();
doReturn(daoBaseMock).when(dao).DAOBase();
```

Comment: DAOBase is BlogCommentDAO's father class, and the method I want to invoke is in DAOBase. Is this the thing?

Comment: I do not understand that "father" class thing you mention. Can you post the definition of DAOBase within BlogCommentDAO? But yes, that is the thing-- DAOBase is null and you call a method on it

Comment: I mean superclass, sorry for that. I always call inheritance as child or father

Comment: I thing the inheritance of dao is the thing, and I fix it. Many thanks. I shouldn't use inheritance, but instead, composition.

Comment: I am sorry but I fail to see inheritance in this code of yours, thus cannot understand what you are describing. Either way, `dao.DAOBase` must be initialized or turned into a mocked method to get rid of the NPE